# Deleting records from a Text file in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I have a text file with 1000 records in it, say 1..2..3...1000.
In Unix, how do i delete only the records 2,13,20,500, 780 and 1000.

Please help me with the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to have changed. Originally you wanted to delete lines by their line number, but now it seems you want to delete lines containing a certain pattern.

There are a couple of options for deleting lines containing `GroupKey`. First, with `sed`:

```
sed '/GroupKey/d' yourFile > newFile
```

Or, secondly with `grep` and a negative/inverted search:

```
grep -v "GroupKey" yourFile > newFile
```

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk '!/GroupKey/' yourFile
```

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks much Mark. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

`sed 'Nd' file`

Here N indicates Nth line in a file.

In the following example, the sed command removes the first line in a file.

`sed '1d' file`

For more details, refer the [link](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/sed-remove-lines-file-unix-examples.html?m=1)

Comment: Thanks Vebbie, I am sorry i have to reframe my question again. There are 10 million records in the text file, and my requirement is i need to delete the lines that has a matching string. i used "Grep GroupKey| wc -l" and found there are 25 matching rows. Now, what would be the syntax to delete those 25 records that has the matching string GroupKey. I tried using  ex command but ended in out of space memory. Thanks.